# Does Talend Open Studio have a sequence container similar to SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, ssis, parallel-processing, talend

Using Talend Open Studio...

- Step 1 - I execute a set of SQL statements in a PostgreSQL database using a tSystem component
- Step 2 - I copy ten PostgreSQL tables into a SQL Server database

As there are no interdependencies, I would like to execute all ten table copy actions simultaneously. If I was using SSIS this would be trivial: place the ten copy table tasks inside a sequence container and use one precedence constraint to link the execute SQL script to the sequence container.

Does Talend Open Studio have a sequence container similar to SSIS?

In Talend Open Studio, I know I can use the OnSubJobOk trigger from the tSystem component and create a connection to each of the ten copy table tasks...but if I can do this with one connection to something like an SSIS sequence container I would prefer to do that because I am lazy...I mean efficient!

The key here is I want to execute all ten copy table tasks in parallel as a way to reduce total runtime.

Thanks for your insights.

Talend Open Studio for Data Integration 6.3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have two options to look out for. Will go one by one.

**tParallelize**

tParallelize component helps you to parallelize and synchronize the execution of numerous subjobs in your main Job. So,  in your case it would execute all ten copy table tasks in parallel subjobs simultaneously and synchronize the execution of within the main Job. Only caveat here is this feature is available only with the subscription version. You can read more about it [here](https://help.talend.com/reader/hCrOzogIwKfuR3mPf%7ELydA/J2Gx1RZDoO6xyhQalZJqUQ).

**Multi thread execution**

this feature is avaialbe on the Extra tab of the Job view. Once you have set up your Talend job you need to select the Multi thread execution check box to activate the Multi-thread Execution feature which will run your logic in parallel. In your case for 10 different Sql Output you will be having 10 database connection established and writing to 10 different connection. More about it [here](https://help.talend.com/reader/mhqCkTBnin7IXmJBUJoocQ/_TTT0Babf_7qRz1ZkQXptA).

One thing to remember here is like SSIS (for SSIS it's number of processors + 2) in Talend too you cannot parallelize more than your number of processor, otherwise it will wait for the processors and will be overhead for processors.